# Display new chart or table in streamlit on demand

Tags: python, streamlit

All the tutorials online I found about streamlit is to create a fix type of table/chart, etc. I.e., the developer will write the code to display a table with the fixed query to extract the data.

Imaging I have this use case:

1. user type in something from the chat window: Show me the population growth per country in the past 3 years. Then we display this line chart
2. user next type in: show me the export in dollar ammount per country in the past 3 years. Then we display another line chart. Note the second chart basically shows up from the bottom and pushes the first chart above like a chat window.

How can I achieve this using streamlit? I am open for other ideas using python framework

Comment: It seems your question is less about making and showing charts and more about how to display some cumulative results where things are "added" to the display instead of "replaced." Is that correct or could you clarify? Using NLP to parse arbitrary user prompts into a result is a topic by itself, separate from how Streamlit can cumulatively display results of some prompt-response scenario.

Comment: Yes, correct . cumulative results and added to the view. just like a chat window

Answer (score 0):

Per the clarifying comment, here's how to handle display of cumulative events:

The trick is to use session state. You need to initialize some data object and store it in session state. Then with each user interaction, a callback can append to that data object. Thus when you display it, you get the cumulative result.

Toy example:

```
import streamlit as st

if 'chat' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.chat = [('A','Hello.')]

def submit():
    st.session_state.chat.append(('B',st.session_state.B))
    st.session_state.chat.append(('A','Some response.'))
    # Clear the text input widget for convenience
    st.session_state.B = ''

for entry in st.session_state.chat:
    st.write(f'{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}')

st.text_input('B\'s Response', key='B', on_change=submit)
```